# How to evaluate $\int_\gamma e^{z}dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute $\int_\gamma e^{z}dz$ where $\gamma(t)=(t,\sin(t)), t\in[0,\pi]$.

I have evaluated using **Fundamental Theorem of Complex Calculus** and got the answer as $e^\pi-1.$

But I am unable to solve it using the definition i.e. $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$.

Can we solve it using definition or **Fundamental Theorem of Complex Calculus** is the only option ?

[image]

Here antiderivative of $e^z $ is $e^z$ itself, then by **Fundamental Theorem of Complex Calculus**  $$\int_\gamma e^{z}dz=e^{\pi+i\sin(\pi)}-e^{0+i sin(0)}=e^\pi-1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FTC is the fastest way. If you want to solve it "directly" you can emulate the FTC:

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=\int_0^\pi e^{t+i \sin(t)} (1+i \cos(t)) dt =\int_0^\pi e^{t} (\cos(\sin(t))+i \sin(\sin(t)) (1+i \cos(t)) dt \\
=\int_0^\pi \bigl( e^{t} \cos(\sin(t))- e^t\sin(\sin(t))\cos(t)\bigr) dt \\+i \int_0^\pi \bigl( e^{t} \cos(\sin(t)) \cos(t)+ e^t \sin(\sin(t))\bigr) dt $$

Now, the FTC tells you that $F(z)=e^z$ is an antiderivative, which means that your integral should turn out to be $F \circ \gamma |_0^{\pi}$

This is 
$$e^{t} (\cos(\sin(t))+i \sin(\sin(t)) =\bigl( e^{t} \cos(\sin(t)) \bigr)+i \bigl( e^t \sin(\sin(t)) \bigr) $$

This shows that 
$$e^{t} (\cos(\sin(t))) $$
is an antiderivative for the first integral, while $ e^t \sin(\sin(t))$ is an antiderivative for the imaginary integral.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was so close but didn't able to find that relation.